# EntityListeners not called

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitylisteners

I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Customizer(value=UsuarioCustomizer.class)
@Indexes({
    @Index(name="idx_login_senha",columnNames={"usuario","senha"})
})
@EntityListeners({Hashr.class})
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  // Fields
```

and here is `Hashr`

```
public class Hashr {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void doHash(Object o){
          // print info
    }
}
```

but it happens that this method is never called...Any ideas? Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be called.  Enable logging on finest and see if any errors are logged.

Ensure you have recompiled/deployed your code.

What environment are you running in?  Ensure you list the listener class in your persistence.xml classes.

Comment: any special tag on persistence.xml to list my listener class?

Comment: this is the output with `finest` log level: http://pastebin.com/dHrN2RK3 everything looks fine, but the listeners aren't called

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any changes to persist.  Try persisting a new object and showing the log, and include the logging that occurs during predeploy if possible as it will show what gets processed.